# Android Custom Notification layout trimmed behind tabs

Tags: android, android-notifications

I see a peculiar problem. The custom layout on my notification content is not completely visible on the notification scroll. I wonder why.

Notice the last notification layout, 2 buttons are partially visible.

[image: here]

Relevant Code

```
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.pickupnotification);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Siddharth" + "2km -> 20km");
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.countDown, "-1:29");
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.from,
            "FROM 2:00pm 14th Jan 2013, Some Address");
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.to,
            "TO4:00pm 14th Jan 2013 Some address");
Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setContent(contentView)
...
notification.contentView = contentView ;
```

I am using a layout with RelativeLayout as root.

Comment: please show your layout. most possibly you are using a relative layout and should avoid overlapping textviews by defining der left/right boundaries...

Comment: Yes I am.. Thanks. Please put your comment in a Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most possibly you are using a relative layout and should avoid overlapping textviews by defining their left/right boundaries.

Like ["To Left Of"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_toLeftOf), ["To Right Of"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_toRightOf).... :)